# Extract the file name and its extension in C

Tags: c, string, filenames

So we have a path string `/home/user/music/thomas.mp3`.

Where is the easy way to extract file name(without extension, "thomas") and it's extension ("mp3") from this string? A function for filename, and for extension. And only GNU libc in our hands.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_FILENAME_SIZE 256

char *filename(char *str) {
    char *result;
    char *last;
    if ((last = strrchr(str, '.')) != NULL ) {
        if ((*last == '.') && (last == str))
            return str;
        else {
            result = (char*) malloc(MAX_FILENAME_SIZE);
            snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%.*s", (int)(last - str), str);
            return result;
        }
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}

char *extname(char *str) {
    char *result;
    char *last;
    if ((last = strrchr(str, '.')) != NULL) {
        if ((*last == '.') && (last == str))
            return "";
        else {
            result = (char*) malloc(MAX_FILENAME_SIZE);
            snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%s", last + 1);
            return result;
        }
    } else {
        return ""; // Empty/NULL string
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know it's all single-byte characters then it's a simple first-week character scanning problem.

Comment: Use `basename` to get `thomas.mp3` then you can use `strrchr` to figure out where the last `.` is to sort out the name and extension.

Comment: Unix doesn't have an explicit notion of extensions (and they aren't technically needed to detect the type of a file). To do what you want, just roll your own function (it's minimal effort)

Comment: @lurker, i can handle out myself, but i wanted to see the way "professionals" from StackOverflow do this. ;)
And just because i'm too lazy at night time. :D

Comment: What's "unprofessional" about using `basename` and `strrchr`? And be aware that the answers you receive may or may not be "professional". ;)

Comment: @JoSo, i know. I just wanted to cut path in my program to 3 pieces, path, filename, extension(if exists).

Comment: @nexfwall: Even if you know, I was telling you that to let you figure out yourself that it's unlikely you will find a function in the C library doing it for you :-)

Comment: @lurker, whats why "professionals" is quoted. :D

Comment: @JoSo, crap. now i really need to switch on my brain, and remember all this pointers arithmetic...

Comment: My answer is 100% GNU compatible, and works in every case. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your actual code (all the other answers so far say to scrap that and do something else, which is good advice, however I am addressing your code as it contains blunders that it'd be good to learn about in advance of next time you try to write something).

Firstly:

```
strncpy(str, result, (size_t) (last-str) + 1);
```

is not good. You have *dest* and *src* around the wrong way; and further this function does not null-terminate the output (unless the input is short enough, which it isn't). Generally speaking `strncpy` is almost never a good solution to a problem; either `strcpy` if you know the length, or `snprintf`.

Simpler and less error-prone would be:

```
snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%.*s", (int)(last - str), str);
```

Similary in the other function,

```
snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%s", last + 1);
```

The `snprintf` function never overflows buffer and always produces a null-terminated string, so long as you get the buffer length right!

Now, even if you fixed those then you have another fundamental problem in that you are returning a pointer to a buffer that is destroyed when the function returns. You could fix `ext` by just returning `last + 1`, since that is null-terminated anyway. But for `filename` you have the usual set of options:

- return a pointer and a length, and treat it as a length-counted string, not a null-terminated one
- return pointer to `malloc`ated memory
- return pointer to static buffer
- expect the caller to pass in a buffer and a buffer length, which you just write into

Finally, returning `NULL` on failure is probably a bad idea; if there is no `.` then return the whole string for `filename`, and an empty string for `ext`. Then the calling code does not have to contort itself with checks for `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you, you explained me a lot of things. I'm just get started with C. Before that i used to code only in bash/perl/lua. But, is sizeof really returns size of an array?

Comment: `sizeof` gives the number of bytes of storage used by a variable (or other expression or type).  If `result` is an array then that is the number of elements in the array, multiplied by the number of bytes per element.

Comment: (when applying `sizeof` to a pointer, be careful to distinguish *the pointer* from *the thing being pointed to*. `sizeof a_pointer` is how many bytes are required to store the pointer value; nothing to do with how big whatever object is that is being pointed to.

Comment: `be careful to distinguish the pointer from the thing being pointed to.` - E.g. don't dereference pointer with *?

Comment: I mean , in your mind. For example, `char *p = "Hello";`. Don't mentally think of `p` as representing the string. The string is somewhere else in memory; `p` tells you where to find it. `sizeof p` is nothing to do with how long the string is (nor is `sizeof *p`, actually).

Comment: +1 for actually addressing the code given. While I agree with the others about starting from scratch, it is nice to see someone who actually takes the time to address what was wrong in the first place instead of merely saying, "Your code is terrible; use this instead."

Answer (score 4):

Use [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) to get the filename and then you can use something like this to get the extension.

```
char *get_filename_ext(const char *filename) {
    const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if(!dot || dot == filename) return "";
    return dot + 1;
}
```

Edit: 
Try something like.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>

static void printFileInfo(char *path) {
    char *bname;
    char *path2 = strdup(path);
    bname = basename(path2);
    printf("%s.%s\n",bname, get_filename_ext(bname));
    free(path2);
}
```

Comment: This will surely work... for file extension. :D
But how will i get file name?
And i see it does not copy the string.

Comment: `printf("%s.%s\n",bname, get_filename_ext(bname));` - basename does not cut file extension.

Comment: this has a small problem, you can't directly compare strings in C, you should use the strcmp() function or one like it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a routine I use for that problem:

***Separates original string*** into separate strings of ***path***, ***file_name*** and ***extension***.

***Will work for Windows and Linux***, relative or absolute style paths.  Will handle directory names with embedded ".".     Will handle file names without extensions.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Example:
// Given path == "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\file.exe"
// will return path_ as   "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3"
// Will return base_ as   "file"
// Will return ext_ as    "exe"
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void GetFileParts(char *path, char *path_, char *base_, char *ext_)
{
    char *base;
    char *ext;
    char nameKeep[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];
    char pathKeep[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];
    char pathKeep2[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN]; //preserve original input string
    char File_Ext[40];
    char baseK[40];
    int lenFullPath, lenExt_, lenBase_;
    char *sDelim={0};
    int   iDelim=0;
    int  rel=0, i;

    if(path)
    {   //determine type of path string (C:\\, \\, /, ./, .\\)
        if(  (strlen(path) > 1) &&

            (
            ((path[1] == ':' ) &&
             (path[2] == '\\'))||

             (path[0] == '\\') ||

             (path[0] == '/' ) ||

            ((path[0] == '.' ) &&
             (path[1] == '/' ))||

            ((path[0] == '.' ) &&
             (path[1] == '\\'))
            )
        )
        {
            sDelim = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
            /*  //   */if(path[0] == '\\') iDelim = '\\', strcpy(sDelim, "\\");
            /*  c:\\ */if(path[1] == ':' ) iDelim = '\\', strcpy(sDelim, "\\"); // also satisfies path[2] == '\\'
            /*  /    */if(path[0] == '/' ) iDelim = '/' , strcpy(sDelim, "/" );
            /* ./    */if((path[0] == '.')&&(path[1] == '/')) iDelim = '/' , strcpy(sDelim, "/" );
            /* .\\   */if((path[0] == '.')&&(path[1] == '\\')) iDelim = '\\' , strcpy(sDelim, "\\" );
            /*  \\\\ */if((path[0] == '\\')&&(path[1] == '\\')) iDelim = '\\', strcpy(sDelim, "\\");
            if(path[0]=='.')
            {
                rel = 1;
                path[0]='*';
            }

            if(!strstr(path, "."))  // if no filename, set path to have trailing delim,
            {                      //set others to "" and return
                lenFullPath = strlen(path);
                if(path[lenFullPath-1] != iDelim)
                {
                    strcat(path, sDelim);
                    path_[0]=0;
                    base_[0]=0;
                    ext_[0]=0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nameKeep[0]=0;         //works with C:\\dir1\file.txt
                pathKeep[0]=0;
                pathKeep2[0]=0;        //preserves *path
                File_Ext[0]=0;
                baseK[0]=0;

                //Get lenth of full path
                lenFullPath = strlen(path);

                strcpy(nameKeep, path);
                strcpy(pathKeep, path);
                strcpy(pathKeep2, path);
                strcpy(path_, path); //capture path

                //Get length of extension:
                for(i=lenFullPath-1;i>=0;i--)
                {
                    if(pathKeep[i]=='.') break; 
                }
                lenExt_ = (lenFullPath - i) -1;

                base = strtok(path, sDelim);
                while(base)
                {
                    strcpy(File_Ext, base);
                    base = strtok(NULL, sDelim);
                }


                strcpy(baseK, File_Ext);
                lenBase_ = strlen(baseK) - lenExt_;
                baseK[lenBase_-1]=0;
                strcpy(base_, baseK);

                path_[lenFullPath -lenExt_ -lenBase_ -1] = 0;

                ext = strtok(File_Ext, ".");
                ext = strtok(NULL, ".");
                if(ext) strcpy(ext_, ext);
                else strcpy(ext_, "");
            }
            memset(path, 0, lenFullPath);
            strcpy(path, pathKeep2);
            if(rel)path_[0]='.';//replace first "." for relative path
            free(sDelim);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Cross-platform. This one can have a good use. But it's too fat for my case, no offence.

Comment: @nexfwall - I prefer "healthy".  but to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old-school algorithm that will do the trick.

```
char path[100] = "/home/user/music/thomas.mp3";
int offset_extension, offset_name;
int len = strlen(path);
int i;
for (i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (path[i] == '.')
        break;
    if (path[i] == '/') {
        i = len;
        break;
    }
}
if (i == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Invalid path");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
offset_extension = i;
for (; i >= 0; i--)
    if (path[i] == '/')
        break;
if (i == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Invalid path");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
offset_name = i;

char *extension, name[100];
extension = &path[offset_extension+1];
memcpy(name, &path[offset_name+1], offset_extension - offset_name - 1);
```

Then you have both information under the variables `name` and `extension`

```
printf("%s %s", name, extension);
```

This will print:

```
thomas mp3
```

Comment: Only it will fail on `/fail.with/this`

Comment: Extensions include a `.` so I guess this is not an issue.

Comment: @ValentinMercier: What if path contains "unix-like hidden" folders? Example: `/home/user/.local/share/applications/app.desktop`

Comment: @nexfwall My algorithm seeks for a `.` from the end so I guess there is no problem

Comment: @nexfwall Just tested and indeed there was no problem at all :) My answer works just fine.

Comment: @ValentinMercier, then now the only problem here, what @JoSo mentioned at comment to my question, path can have no file extension. But have a dot in the name of folder. Example: `/home/user/.config/prog/config`. And this algorithm should be wrapped in a function.

Comment: @nexfwall Ok then I will edit my answer, this is easy to fix :) I'll notify you once done.

Comment: @nexfwall Done, now it handles the issue correctly and the extension string will just be empty if it does not exist.

Comment: or "edge" cases

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. But I tend to use strtok for things like this.

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_TOKENS  20  /* Some reasonable values */
#define MAX_STRING  128 /* Easy enough to make dynamic with mallocs */

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="/home/user/music/thomas.mp3";
  char sep[] = "./";
  char collect[MAX_TOKENS][MAX_STRING];

  /* Not really necessary, since \0 is added inplace. I do this out of habit. */
  memset(collect, 0, MAX_TOKENS * MAX_STRING);
  char * pch = strtok (str, sep);
  int ccount = 0;    

  if(pch != NULL) {
    /* collect all seperated text */
    while(pch != NULL) { 
        strncpy( collect[ccount++], pch, strlen(pch));
        pch = strtok (NULL, sep);
    }
  }

  /* output tokens. */
  for(int i=0; i<ccount; ++i)
    printf ("Token: %s\n", collect[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

This is a rough example, and it makes it easy to deal with the tokens afterwards. Ie the last token is the extension. Second last is the basename and so on. 
I also find it useful for rebuilding paths for different platforms - replace / with \.